# Differentiate the following function: $y = \frac{2x^2 + 6\sqrt{x} }{9x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My answer is $- \dfrac{1}{9 \sqrt{x} }$, however, the program I am using states that I am wrong. Where have I went wrong?

Comment: The set up is wrong its y = 2x^2 + 6 square root x divided by 9x

Answer (score 2):

$y=2x^2+\frac{2}{3}x^{-1/2}$. Now use the power rule to differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

$4x-\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: That doesn't really state anything; it's just an expression.

Answer (score 1):

$$y = 2x^2 + \frac{6\sqrt x}{9x} = 2x^2 +\frac {2}{3\sqrt x} = 2x^2 + \frac 23\cdot x^{-1/2}$$

$$y' = 4x - \frac 12\cdot\frac 23 \cdot x^{-3/2} =  4x - \frac{1}{3x^{3/2}}$$

**EDIT:**

Given the OP's comments and attempted edit, it seems that the function of interest is intended to be $$y = \frac{2x^2 + 6\sqrt{x}}{9x}= \frac 29 x + \frac 23\cdot x^{-1/2}$$
If so, then
$$\begin{align} \frac{dx}{dy} & = \frac 29 - \frac 12\cdot\frac 23 \cdot x^{-3/2}\\ \\ 
& =  \frac 29 - \frac{1}{3x^{3/2}}\\ \\
& = \frac{2x^{3/2} - 3}{9x^{3/2}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: The set up is wrong its y = 
2x^2 + 6 square root x divided by 9x

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: So was my answer right?

Comment: No, the answer is what you see in my post. $$y' = \frac 29 - \frac{1}{3x^{3/2}}
= \frac{2x^{3/2} - 3}{9x^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of your first term is just $4x$ and if you use the power rule for the second one, you get $-\frac{1}{3}\times x^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ so eventually you get 
$$4x-\frac{1}{3}\times x^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$y = \frac{2x^{2}}{9x} + \frac{6x^\frac{1}{2}}{9x}=\frac{2x}{9} + \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Then $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{9} -\frac{2}{3}⋅-\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}$